# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

i need your help, when i try to compile my new app without any addition of dependences and classpath i get this exception

- android studio ver 21.1
- ubuntu 15.4 32bit

  **Error Execution failed for task app clean.**

  > Unable to delete directory: .../app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/23.4.0/jars

Comment: Is your project in a folder like Dropbox or some "read-only" directories?

Comment: it is not in dropbox, but i got some concept about read-only directories, let me check it,

Comment: i try to change mode to rwx but it do nothing

Comment: Finally i find the solution.     If you are using Android Studio 2.0 Beta, this issue might appear (more likely if you are working on NTFS filesystem) and it seems like the "Instant Run" is the culprit. Search for "Instant Run" in settings and uncheck the box.

Comment: Working for me Ubuntu 16.04 64bit
Maybe you can try this tips http://stackoverflow.com/a/41304696/3690630

Answer (score 4):

Running android studio as administrator fixed the problem for me. (windows 10)

Answer (score 3):

1. File --> Invalidate Caches/Restart...
2. Build -- > Rebuild Project

Answer (score 1):

Simply do following things.

1. Open Task Manager.
2. Go to Users Tab.
3. Select current user(which is you).
4. Select "AndroidInterface"
5. Click on Disconnect button.

Then Rebuild project it will work...

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.

Clean project from Terminal using this command 'gradlew clean'.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Gradle process holds file locks, so either kill any java.exe processes manually or be more precise and kill all Gradle daemons by issuing this command in your project root directory:

```
gradlew daemon --stop
```

This will stop all daemons of particular Gradle version.