# Execution failed for app:clean in android studio 2.2

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-2.2

I currently switch to android studio 2.2 and I have a big problem. when I build project to deploy on emulator I got this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/D/Document/WorkSpace/Android/Test/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/animated-vector-drawable/25.0.0/jars
```

I clean that path and again it tell me that:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/D/Document/WorkSpace/Android/Test/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/cardview-v7/25.0.0/jars
```

I clean it handy and again:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:clean'.
> Unable to delete directory: /mnt/D/Document/WorkSpace/Android/Test/app/build/intermediates/exploded-aar/com.android.support/support-compat/25.0.0/jars/libs
```

I don't know how many steps exists and if I pass all these steps, may be I mentally!
I don't have these issues in android 1.4. is this a bug about android studio or related to my system(Arch Linux)?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finally fix it!
after:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
```

add this line of code to build.gradle(Module: app) file:

```
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

it will delete all jar and lib files from build your directory.
hope to enjoy :)

Comment: Custom clean tasks are scheduled to be deprecated, if they are not already. Just a note

Comment: @milosmns
and what is the replacement for custom clean tasks?

Comment: I don't think there is a replacement, they just don't want us to use it anymore. Not sure why though

Answer (score 0):

Disable Instant Run. It is in 
File -> Settings -> Build,Execution -> Instant Run

This worked for me.

Comment: I doubt that Instant Run had anything to do with the locked JAR. It was probably Android Studio that stopped all JVMs when you toggled that setting, so you can probably turn it on again now. Also, Instant Run is now updated so it works much better, it's worth trying out.

Comment: Ohh Thanks! I will surely try out.

Answer (score 0):

For me there was a stuck debug test inside of Android Studio and `mockable-jar` was used inside of that JVM and couldn't be deleted.

What I had to do is.. stop the frozen JVM from Task Manager, then clean.

What I'll do the next time this happens is.. stop the frozen debug test from Android Studio, then clean.